# How to stop a running function from outside

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to stop a running Javascript function from outside of this function?

Comment: Not within the JavaScript runtime system. You have to stop whatever is supporting it; close the browser window, kill the Node.js process, etc.

Comment: Define "running" and give some context/example. Does it include an asynchronous action or what you'd like to "stop"?

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample code of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also remember that Javascript is single-threaded, so there is no such thing as several functions running at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no "outside" of a function in JS. Once the running script is "outside" the function the function is completed running.

**UPDATE**

If there is some condition that could become true while a particular function is running that you would like to cause that function to exit, then you can check for that condition inside the function at regular intervals and exit the function if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 supports multithreading with [web workers](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-threading-html5-web-workers/)

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: By stopping people from believing that JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: That statement is *only* true for HTML5 and certain browsers. We can't assume that the OP can, is, or even wants to use HTML5, so I would suggest clarifying your answer and/or at least providing an example of how web workers can help the OP. Otherwise your answer should probably just be a comment.